# Congruence to a power

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I know a^m = 1 mod p
How do I know that a^(mp)= 1 mod p^2?

Can someone please explain to me some rules of congruence regarding powers?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a^m\equiv1\pmod p\implies a^m=1+kp$$ for some integer $k$

Now $a^{mp}=(a^m)^p=(1+kp)^p=1+kp^2+\text{ terms containing }p^2\equiv1\pmod{p^2}$

Comment: If we let p=2, (a^m)^p = 1 + 2kp + k^2p^2 = 1 + 2kp mod p^2... thank you for your help

Comment: @B.Drennan, As $p=2,$  $$2kp=2^2k$$ right?

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you!!